# Call button click event on pressing Enter - c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am new to c# - I want to trigger button click event on pressing enter. My code not working properly -

issue is that when i press enter on submitting some value, it displays messagebox which it should show but on pressing Enter for OK button of Messagebox, it automatically triggers button click event again even i don't press enter or enter any other value.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int n1, n2 = 0;
    private static readonly Random getrandom = new Random();
    private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
    public int GetRandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        { // synchronize
            return getrandom.Next(min, max);
        }
    }

    public int tQuestion()
    {
        n1 = GetRandomNumber(2, 11);
        n2 = GetRandomNumber(2, 11);

        string tQues = n1 + " x " + n2 + " = ";

        label1.Text = tQues;

        return 0;
    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tQuestion();

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(tb_KeyDown);
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string tAns = textBox1.Text;
        int answer = n1 * n2;

        string tOrgAns = answer.ToString();

        if (tAns == tOrgAns)
            MessageBox.Show("Your answer is Corect", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation );
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Your answer is WRONG", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Focus();
        tQuestion();
    }

    static void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            button1_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

Moreover, code only works if i remove `static` from `static void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)` - otherwise it gives error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property

Please help me - i am new to c# & .Net

Comment: Please add the WinForms or WPF tag to your message. It's extremelly useful for tag filters.

Comment: Sorry,I tried that - but i was unable to understand that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling while textbox is focused. Better option is to create a separate function and call that from both.

I have made changes to your code. It's working for me. You need to link `tb_keyDown` event with `keyDown` property in Textbox Properties.

Try this code:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int n1, n2 = 0;
    private static readonly Random getrandom = new Random();
    private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
    public int GetRandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        { // synchronize
            return getrandom.Next(min, max);
        }
    }

    public int tQuestion()
    {
        n1 = GetRandomNumber(2, 11);
        n2 = GetRandomNumber(2, 11);

        string tQues = n1 + " x " + n2 + " = ";

        label1.Text = tQues;

        return 0;
    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tQuestion();

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //make it empty. You need to attach tb_KeyDown event in properties
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckAnswer();
    }

    void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            CheckAnswer();
        }
    }

    private void CheckAnswer()
    {
        string tAns = textBox1.Text;
        int answer = n1 * n2;

        string tOrgAns = answer.ToString();

        if (tAns == tOrgAns)
            MessageBox.Show("Your answer is Corect", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation );
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Your answer is WRONG", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Focus();
        tQuestion();
 }   



}
```

Comment: This is buggy. How many times will you attach `tb_KeyDown` as an event handler of `textBox1.KeyDown`, if you do this every time on `textBox1_TextChanged`?

Comment: Oh i didn't see. I have edited my answer and made correction. So undo -1 Please.

Comment: downvote retracted of course

Comment: Thankyou Shumail92 for your help. much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Extract button click event handler into separate method (e.g. `VerifyAnswer`) and call it from both places:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VerifyAnswer();
}

// NOTE: static modifier removed
private void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)        
        VerifyAnswer();
}

private void VerifyAnswer()
    string tAns = textBox1.Text;
    int answer = n1 * n2;

    string tOrgAns = answer.ToString();

    if (tAns == tOrgAns)
        MessageBox.Show("Your answer is Corect", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation );
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Your answer is WRONG", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox1.Focus();
    tQuestion();
}
```

Don't try to manually execute event handlers - their purpose is handling events only.

Comment: Okay but where ``tb_KeyDown`` is called now ?

Comment: @SigmaElporto that's should be handler of `KeyDown` event of textbox (or whatever control you used). E.g. if you want to handle `KeyDown` event of textbox, you should open designer, select it, go to Properties window, select Events tab, and attach this handler to `KeyDown` event (select it in drop-down).

Comment: THanks a lot everyone for Help. I have voted UP.

Comment: @SigmaElporto and how accepted answer differs from mine?

Comment: I wanted to accept both - I accepted that answer because it had code and instructions for keydown event as well. But on the other hand, i voted for you which i didn't do for that.

Comment: @SigmaElporto it's up to you what to accept :) just wanted to know if there is some difference besides time of answer

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a [static parameterless keylistener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx), which you could have running separately in the static method to check for key input. And then parse the key inputs there

Answer (score 1):

That's because of this code:

```
static void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button1_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Remove that handler and set the `AcceptButton` of the `Form` to `button1`. The `AcceptButton` is a property you can simply set in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access instance members from static members

Either you have to

- Make the method an instance method (remove the static keyword)
- Make the field/method a static (add the static keyword)

The one you choose will depend on whether the field should be shared across all instances or not.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for that

```
button1.PerformClick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't attempt to *trigger* a button click.  Essentially what you should do is refactor your code so that the event handlers are separated from the actual implementation. e.g.

```
ButtonClick(...)
{
   ExecuteMethod();
}

KeyDown(...)
{
   ExecuteMethod();
}

ExecuteMethod()
{
   // Actual implementation.
}
```

This disassociates the event you are subscribing to from the implementation.  That way, in the future, if you wish to add new buttons or change around event handlers, your actual logical implementation remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

please, check below options:

(1)Can you not use AcceptButton in for the Forms Properties Window? This sets the default behaviour for the "Enter" key press, but you are still able to use other shortcuts.
(2)

```
static void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == (char)13)
    {
        button1_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```